# Returning namedtuple from function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, namedtuple

I am just looking to understand why I get the following results

From the following code

```
def sendHTTP(httpStatus):   
    status_code = 400
    reason = "Unauthorized"
    httpStatus(Code=req.status_code,Desc=req.reason)
    return httpStatus

if __name__ == '__main__':
    httpStatus = namedtuple('httpStatus','Code Desc')
    http_results = sendHTTP(httpStatus)
    print "1:",http_results
```

Print result is:

```
1: <class '__main__.httpStatus'>
```

while

```
def sendHTTP(httpStatus):

    status_code = 400
    reason = "Unauthorized"
    b = httpStatus(Code=req.status_code,Desc=req.reason)
    return b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    httpStatus = namedtuple('httpStatus','Code Desc')
    http_results = sendHTTP(httpStatus)
    print "1:",http_results
```

Print result is:

```
1: httpStatus(Code=401, Desc='Unauthorized')
```

Could someone explain why adding the `b` variable gives the values instead of the variable name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the first case, you aren't doing anything with the resulting instance from the call of the `httpStatus`, and then simply returning the namedtuple class which was passed as an argument.

Whereas in the second, `b` is *assigned* the instance of `httpStatus` which is created with

```
b = httpStatus(Code=req.status_code,Desc=req.reason)
```

which is then returned.

If you wanted the same (correct) behavior in both cases, you would want to directly

```
return httpStatus(Code=req.status_code,Desc=req.reason)
```

in your first case, instead of having the useless call without a return statement *or* assignment.

Comment: Got it. I assume the following code created the instance: `httpStatus = namedtuple('httpStatus','Code Desc')`

Answer (score 2):

In the first function you are *ignoring* the instance created, then return the `namedtuple` class. You could just have printed the class directly without using a function for the same result:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> httpStatus = namedtuple('httpStatus','Code Desc')
>>> print httpStatus
<class '__main__.httpStatus'>
```

In the second function, you are assigning the instance you create to a variable, then return whatever the variable references (i.e. the instance you created).

You could forgo the variable and just return the instance directly:

```
return httpStatus(Code=req.status_code, Desc=req.reason)
```

Note that this has nothing to do with named tuples. This would happen for *any class*; you are returning the class object itself.